# Highlighting/selecting an image based on text entered in an textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I’m looking for a sample where an image, out of several, is selected/highlighted/slightly zoomed depending on the input entered in a textbox. For instance in below case, as the credit card number is entered appropriated logo is selected/highlighted accordingly.

|Visa|Mastercard||Amex|Diners|       <== Images

|**________________________**|       <== Card Number textbox

I’m not a frontend developer myself but I presume JavaScript/jQuery is the right technology to implement something like the above? The page is written in ASP.NET MVC.

I appreciate any pointers.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome thanks!

Here is what I ended up doing. Thought it might be useful for someone else.

```
        function checkCCNo() {
        var cardimg;
        var cctx = document.getElementById("ccno");
        switch (cctx.value.substring(0, 1)) {
        case "4":
            cardimg = document.getElementById("visa");
            break;
        case "5":
            cardimg = document.getElementById("mastercard");
            break;
        }
        if (cardimg) { // Highlight the approprite credit card image
            $(cardimg).css({ "background-color": "", "opacity": "" });
            $(cardimg).css("border", "solid 2px silver");
            $(cardimg).animate({ width: "40px" }, "fast");
        }
        // Fade out the other credit card images
        var cardimgArr = ["visa", "mastercard"];
        for (var i = 0; i < cardimgArr.length; i++) {
            var image = "#" + cardimgArr[i];
            if (cardimg == undefined || cardimg.id != $(image).attr("id")) {
                $(image).css("border", "none");
                $(image).animate({ width: "36px", opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to improve the code, I'd be thankful to hear it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

You could do something as simple as add a small border around the image. You could detect the card type by the starting number...5 is Mastercard...4 is Visa etc. and highlight the appropriate image.

You'd want to give each of your images a unique ID attribute and a class so you can style all images at once. For example:

**Edit: There were some bugs. Had to pass in the id. Corrected.**

```
<img id="mc" class="cc" src="mastercard.jpg" />
<img id="visa" class="cc" src="visa.jpg" />
<input id="ccno" type="text" oninput="checkCCNo('ccno');" />
```

Your css could be:

```
.cc {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Your JavaScript would then be:

```
function checkCCNo(id){
    var cardimg;
    var source = document.getElementById(id);
    switch (source.value.substring(0,1)){
        case "4":
            cardimg = document.getElementById("visa");
            break;
        case "5":
            cardimg = document.getElementById("mc");
            break;
    }
    if(cardimg) {
        cardimg.style.borderStyle = "solid";
        cardimg.style.borderColor = "red";
        cardimg.style.borderWidth = "2px";            
    }
}
```

You can add additional cards by simply adding more cases. If you don't want to increase the border to highlight, you simply change what you do within the last if block such as swap out images etc.

You could also use this function to do some validation on the card number if you wished.